# When is Prim(A) of an infinite discrete group hausdorff ?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, harmonic-analysis

Does anyone know, if the following result has been proved ?

Let G be an infinite discrete group. A = L1(G) it's algebra and Prim(A) the set of prime ideals with spectral topology.
The result is :
faPrim(A) is Hausdorff if and only if G is a FC-Group.

Comment: I should know this, but: is your condition equivalent to G being a Type I group? (It feels stronger but I can't immediately think of a counter-example)

Comment: If true, this feels like something that Kaniuth might have worked on... I will try to look up details when I next have a free moment in the office.

Comment: @Yemon: the infinite dihedral group is type I, but $Prim(A)$ is not Hausdorff ...

Comment: Merci Alain - I should have remembered that!

Comment: Just to clarify: I've usually seen Prim(A) used to denote the primitive ideal space. Do you really mean "prime ideals"?

Comment: The condition, that G is a FC-group means, that every conjugate class of G is finitely generated, but the infinite dihedral group is no FC-group.
Yes, Prim(A) is the primitive ideal space.

Answer (score 2):

I asked Eberhard Kaniuth, if he knows something about the problem.
Here is his answer :

If G is a FC-Group, then Prim(L^1(G)) is Hausdorff.
If  Prim(L^1(G)) is Hausdorff and G amenable, then G is a FC-Group
Probably G need not to be amenable. He don't know any counterexample.